# How can I prevent my React component from rendering multiple times while authenticating a user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-hooks

I have my App.js re-rendering multiple times. Is there a way to optimize that? `<React.StrictMode>` is already removed. I also tried without `useMemo` and having these 3 variables in the array for `useEffect`.

```
export default function App() {
    const { instance, accounts, inProgress } = useMsal();

    const callLogin = useMemo(() => {
        return () => {
            console.log("Inside callLogin");
            const isAuthenticated = accounts.length > 0;

            if (!isAuthenticated && inProgress === InteractionStatus.None) {
                instance.loginRedirect();
            }
        };
    }, [instance, accounts, inProgress]);

    console.log("I'm inside App.js!");

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("App.js useEffect");
        callLogin();
    }, [callLogin]);
    return 
        (<SomeComponent />)
}
```

This is what it looks like after *one* hard clean refresh. You can ignore Kendo warnings.

[image]

This is how App.js is called in index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
    <App />
  </MsalProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I removed the entire `useEffect` hook and this is what I ended up with

[image]

Comment: I doubt it’s connected with your problem, but you can substitute `useCallback` for `useMemo` and remove a level of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

Your `useMsal` hook outputs `inProgress` state variable which appears to be a boolean flag for the loading state of a promise. These commonly goes from `undefined` to `true` to `false` --- which would cause all sub-components to render 3 times, once for each state change.

Your `callLogin()` function should be a `useCallback` with it's dependencies set.

You should also be memoizing your `<SomeComponent>` using `memo()` to React *when* it should be re-rendering that component. Right now, your `SomeComponent` just renders anytime the state changes.

Try using this:

```
const MemoizedSomeComponent = memo(({accounts}) => {
  console.log('Memoized render accounts =', accounts);
  return <span>Hello World</span>
}

export default function App() {
  const { instance, accounts, inProgress } = useMsal();

  const callLogin = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("Inside callLogin");
    const isAuthenticated = accounts.length > 0;

    if (!isAuthenticated && inProgress === InteractionStatus.None) {
        instance.loginRedirect();
    }
  }, [instance.loginRedirect, inProgress, accounts, InteractionStatus.None]);

  console.log("I'm inside App.js!");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("App.js useEffect");
    callLogin();
  }, [callLogin]);

  return <MemoizedSomeComponent accounts={accounts} />;
}
```

Renders are easier to deal with when your app is broken down into smaller parts. [Here's a working sandbox template](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-preventing-rerenders-in-async-call-hooks-icvpz6) I created which demonstrates a barebones approach to using `useContext`, `useMemo`, `useCallback` and `memo()` to avoid re-renders and have better control over your components.

[This particular response](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156) on Preventing rerenders with React.memo and `useContext` hook is extremely informative, as well as [this entire section on useContext](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useContext) from the `React Beta` docs which really made things click for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please? If I break my `App.js` wouldn't that mean the other components would be siblings? And they would also be children to `<MsalProvider>`?

Comment: Correct. Sorry I realize I did not phrase that properly. The `<SubComponent>` needs to not render at the same time as the `useMsal` hook output. Adding an example which should work.